# How to convert SHA-1 to 28-character string ( For FB Login in Android App)

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, google-play, sha

FB login is working in APKs generated with debug,release build and app installed from Play Store on MotoG4(i use it for app testing). But FB login isn't working in app downloaded from Play Store(All Android Devices Except the MotoG4 i use for app testing). 
The error says

> "The key hash does not match any stored key hashes"

I can not log the error as it doesn't appear on my MotoG4 device.

I have a added Development Key Hash & Release Key Hash in FB Developer Console.

[Development Key Hash & Release Key Hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kwZi.jpg)

I have enabled app signing on play store also.
[app signing play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2ORq.jpg)

I found an article where one of the suggestion is to add play store signing SHA-1 in FB Developer console [medium link](https://medium.com/@akashmahali/facebook-login-google-sign-in-not-working-on-android-app-in-production-5febd9537f92)

Google Provides three kind of certificate fingerprints(SHA-1,MD5 & SHA-256) but none matches the required in FB developer console. FB developer console only accept 28-character string. Is there anyway i can convert the SHA-1 to 28-character string?